# SSRS Report Parameter - using abs with a Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to have a parameter on a report that allows the user to enter a max and min value to filter on. I want to use the same parameter so what ever value is entered becomes both up upper and lower value. To get the lower value I want to convert the Parameter value into a negative number.

Using

```
=abs(Parameters!.Name.Value)
```

I get a long error message:

```
Overload resolution failed because no Public 'Abs' can be called without narrowing conversion
```

Thought this was due to the parameter value getting turned in to string so added?

```
=abs(CDbl(Parameters!.Name.Value))
```

But then the conversion does not take place, I get the value I am trying to convert.

How do I convert the parameter value into a negative number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abs will always be positive, so just multiply by -1

```
=abs(CDbl(Parameters!.Name.Value)) * -1
```

Comment: realised by multiplying the value by -1 I did not need to convert, works perfectly well without the need for `abs` or `CDbl`

Comment: @FredTheDog - what happens if the user enters a negative number?

Comment: Turns it into a positive. Might not give you what you need, for me it worked as I wanted the same value to be both positive and negative.

Comment: Negative multiplied by positive gives negative. Negative multiplied by negative gives positive.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you, I thought you always wanted to get a negative number, regardless of what the user entered.

Comment: aahhh ok, probably didn't explain myself to begin with, but we got there! I was under the impression the `abs` function would have switched the number for me, but now realise from your post it would always return the positive, hence the need to then turn it negative with the -1

Comment: Anyways, works like a dream just having the -1 so whatever the user enters I can get both the positive and negative for my filter